# Unexpected output while calling octave script from php

Tags: php, octave

I am calling Octave script from PHP and passing parameters to it. But I get the unexpected output.

The PHP code I'm using to pass arguments and call the Octave script is:

```
$a=8;
$b=3;
$cmd = "C:\Octave\Octave4\bin\octave-cli C:\wamp\www\dspace\add.m $a $b";
$ex = passthru($cmd, $op);
var_dump($ex);
```

My Octave script:

```
arglist = argv();
 a = arglist{1};
 b = arglist{2};

function f (a,b)
  a + b
endfunction

printf(f(a,b));
```

The output get is:

```
ans = 107
```

Expected output is:

```
11
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Octave are you using? Are you calling the script on Windows?

Comment: @James, Octave4, yes calling the script on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the [ASCII codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for the character "8" which is 56 and "3" which is 51 so the result is 107. Convert the strings to numbers:

```
arglist = argv();

a = str2num (arglist{1});
b = str2num (arglist{2});

function ret = f (a,b)
  ret = a + b;
endfunction

printf("%i", f(a,b));
```